# Caminho do arquivo com erro para executar mp3

Tags: python

Estava resolvendo um exercício proposto em um curso que consistia em executar um arquivo mp3 passando o caminho do mesmo, pesquisei um pouco e cheguei a esta código:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\Downloads\c.mp3')
```

Quando executava dava erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver foi proposto que eu colocasse desta forma:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\\Downloads\\c.mp3')
```

Não entendi porque das 2 \\ para o caminho do arquivo, alguém saberia explicar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A famigerada "barra invertida" utilizada no windows tem uma função no python, nos sistemas unix, nas expressoes regulares e algumas outras linguagens de programação, como C e Perl, a função dela é indicar que o caracter seguinte deve ser tratado de forma especial, nesse contexto é chamada também de caracater de escape que pode formar uma sequencia de scape, veja algumas delas (note a "Contrabarra"):

```
\a - BEL Bell
\b - BS (ascii) BackSpace
\f - FF Formfeed
\n - LF NewLine
\r - CR Carriage Return
\t - HT Horizontal Tabulation
\v - VT (ascii) Vertical Tabulation
\' - Apóstrofe (Single quotation mark)
\" - Aspas (Double quotation mark)
\\ - Contrabarra
\ooo - Caracter ASCII em notação octal
\xhhh - Caracter ASCII em notação hexadecimal
```

Como o python também utiliza a barra invertida como inicio de sequencias de escape, no caso da sua pergunta, ele esta fazendo uma espécie de "escape do escape", ou seja, indicando para considerar o próximo caracter como um caracter comum e não como início de uma sequencia de scape.