# Python - Indicação do Path de um arquivo para leitura

Tags: python

Estou tentando estabelecer o caminho para ler uma tabela de *excel* pelo *xlrd*.

Porém obtenho uma resposta dizendo que o *C: não pode ser utilizado*. Como definir corretamente o caminho dos arquivos a serem utilizados?

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls", on_demand = True)
sheet.cell(0,0).value
```

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import xlrd
>   ----> 2 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls")
>         3 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls",
>   on_demand = True)
>         4 sheet.cell(0,0).value
>
> C:\Users\rdmsouza\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py
>   in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap,
>   file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand,
>   ragged_rows)
>       393         peek = file_contents[:peeksz]
>       394     else:
>   --> 395         with open(filename, "rb") as f:
>       396             peek = f.read(peeksz)
>       397     if peek == b"PK\x03\x04": # a ZIP file
>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'C:\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls'

Answer (score 1):

Python usa a barra invertida para inicio de sequencia de scape, ou seja, quando o interpretador encontra uma "barra invertida" ele espera o proximo caracter como sendo "especial", ou "de controle". Então o que vc tem de fazer é informar que é um caracter normal, colocando a propria barra invertida antes, isto é, troque todas as barras simples por barras duplas, assim:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\rdmsouza\\Documents\\python...
```

[Para complementar veja essa resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225596/7412)

Comment: Ou, pode-se usar a "/" pra frente também - o Python a interepreta como um separador de diretórios, mesmo no Windows, justamente por conta da duplicidade da "\" invertida.

Comment: @jsbueno Verdade, mas o problema é quando vc depende de variáveis externas das quais vc não tem controle, então vc tem que saber do detalhe do scape para, necessariamente, fazer a conversão.

Comment: Não tem "variáveis externas" nesse caso - a "\" só 'eum caractere de escape se está numa string digitada dentro do código fonte em Python. Se alguém digitar ma "\" numa entrada de "input", ou se uma "\" for lida de um arquivo texto, ou de um banco de dados, será sempre um caractere separado, que funciona como separador. Experimente: faça `print(input())` e digite uma única "\" ou algumas das combinações de escape, como \n, \t, etc...

Comment: Ok, nao não tenho tempo e nem me interessa procurar agora (mesmo pq meu mundo, atualmente, é, exclusivamente, Linux), mas... SIM! em alguns contextos pode-se ter ENORMES problemas (e eu já os tive). Não é por acaso que existem libs para lidar com isso

Comment: Mas... deu vontade de fazer um teste, se nao me angano foi com configuracoes baseadas em arquivos yaml (python 2 alguma coisa), mas não.... acho q nao! nao vou entrar no windows só para isto. :-)

Comment: O que eu escrevi so bre Python está correto - é que arquivos YAML podem usar escaping com exatamente a mesma sintaxe que o Python - veja:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

Comment: Sim, e o que escrevi tb esta correto, eu disse "variáveis externas", ou seja se vc distribui uma app que depende de um arquivo `yaml` do qual vc não tem participação direta, isto é, construido no ambiente de produção por um outro profisssional\time, vc esta lidando uma **variável externa**, capisce? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar tambem um "r" no começo de um caminho, mais ou menos assim:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\\Users\rdmsouza\Documents\python\programas\dados.xls")
```

Ai você vai perceber que toda inicial depois do \ vai ficar com uma cor diferente.